# Unable to install ia32-libs

Tags: debian, skype, dpkg, dependencies

I am running Debian wheezy/sid x86_64 and I am trying to install the official Skype package. However I seem to be having a few dependency issues that I can't resolve. I have enabled multiarch, the issue seems to be that there is a huge amount of dependencies to install `ia32-libs-i386` (dependency of `ia32-libs` which is needed for Skype), all i386. I don't understand this as I am installing the 64-bit version, could someone please explain what I should do here? Here is a console log:

```
root@debian:~# dpkg -i skype*amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package skype.
(Reading database ... 110454 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking skype (from skype-debian_4.0.0.8-1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:
 skype depends on ia32-libs; however:
  Package ia32-libs is not installed.
 skype depends on ia32-libs-gtk; however:
  Package ia32-libs-gtk is not installed.

dpkg: error processing skype (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype
root@debian:~# apt-get install ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-i386
 skype : Depends: ia32-libs-gtk but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@debian:~# apt-get install ia32-libs-i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs-i386:i386 : Depends: freeglut3:i386 (>= 2.6.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: lesstif2:i386 (>= 1:0.95.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libacl1:i386 (>= 2.2.49-4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libasyncns0:i386 (>= 0.3-1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libattr1:i386 (>= 1:2.4.44-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libaudio2:i386 (>= 1.9.2-4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libaudiofile1:i386 (>= 0.2.6-8) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libavahi-client3:i386 (>= 0.6.27-2+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libavahi-common3:i386 (>= 0.6.27-2+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libbsd0:i386 (>= 0.2.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libcap2:i386 (>= 1:2.19-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libcomerr2:i386 (>= 1.41.12-4stable1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libcups2:i386 (>= 1.4.4-7+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libcurl3:i386 (>= 7.21.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libdbus-1-3:i386 (>= 1.2.24-4+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libdirectfb-1.2-9:i386 (>= 1.2.10.0-4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libdrm-intel1:i386 (>= 2.4.21-1~squeeze3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (>= 2.4.21-1~squeeze3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.21-1~squeeze3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libedit2:i386 (>= 2.11-20080614-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libesd0:i386 (>= 0.2.41-8) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libexif12:i386 (>= 0.6.19-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libexpat1:i386 (>= 2.0.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libflac8:i386 (>= 1.2.1-2+b1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libfltk1.1:i386 (>= 1.1.10-2+b1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libfontconfig1:i386 (>= 2.8.0-2.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.4.2-2.1+squeeze3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgcrypt11:i386 (>= 1.4.5-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgdbm3:i386 (>= 1.8.3-9) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 7.7.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (>= 7.7.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libglu1-mesa:i386 (>= 7.7.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgnutls26:i386 (>= 2.8.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgpg-error0:i386 (>= 1.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgphoto2-2:i386 (>= 2.4.6-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgphoto2-port0:i386 (>= 2.4.6-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 (>= 1.8.3+dfsg-4squeeze2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libice6:i386 (>= 2:1.0.6-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libidn11:i386 (>= 1.15-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libieee1284-3:i386 (>= 0.2.11-6) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libjack0:i386 (>= 1:0.118+svn3796-7) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libjpeg62:i386 (>= 6b1-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libjpeg8:i386 (>= 8b-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libk5crypto3:i386 (>= 1.8.3+dfsg-4squeeze2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libkeyutils1:i386 (>= 1.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libkrb5-3:i386 (>= 1.8.3+dfsg-4squeeze2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libkrb5support0:i386 (>= 1.8.3+dfsg-4squeeze2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: liblcms1:i386 (>= 1.18.dfsg-1.2+b3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (>= 2.4.23-7.2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libltdl7:i386 (>= 2.2.6b-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: liblzo2-2:i386 (>= 2.03-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libmpg123-0:i386 (>= 1.12.1-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libnspr4-0d:i386 (>= 4.8.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libnss-ldap:i386 (>= 264-2.2)
                       Depends: libnss3-1d:i386 (>= 3.12.8-1+squeeze4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libogg0:i386 (>= 1.2.0~dfsg-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libopenal1:i386 (>= 1:1.12.854-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libpam-ldap:i386 (>= 184-8.5)
                       Depends: libpam0g:i386 (>= 1.1.1-6.1+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libpng12-0:i386 (>= 1.2.44-1+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libpopt0:i386 (>= 1.16-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libpulse0:i386 (>= 0.9.21-3+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsamplerate0:i386 (>= 0.1.7-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsane:i386 (>= 1.0.21-9) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsasl2-2:i386 (>= 2.1.23.dfsg1-7) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsdl1.2debian:i386 (>= 1.2.15) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libselinux1:i386 (>= 2.0.96-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:i386 (>= 2.2.4.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsm6:i386 (>= 2:1.1.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsndfile1:i386 (>= 1.0.21-3+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsqlite3-0:i386 (>= 3.7.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libssh2-1:i386 (>= 1.2.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 (>= 1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libstdc++5:i386 (>= 1:3.3.6-20) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsvga1:i386 (>= 1:1.4.3-29) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsysfs2:i386 (>= 2.1.0+repack-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libtasn1-3:i386 (>= 2.7-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libtdb1:i386 (>= 1.2.1-2+b1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libtiff4:i386 (>= 3.9.4-5+squeeze3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libts-0.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0-7) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libusb-0.1-4:i386 (>= 2:0.1.12-16) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libuuid1:i386 (>= 2.17.2-9) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libvorbis0a:i386 (>= 1.3.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libvorbisenc2:i386 (>= 1.3.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libvorbisfile3:i386 (>= 1.3.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libwrap0:i386 (>= 7.6.q-19) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libx11-6:i386 (>= 2:1.3.3-4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libx86-1:i386 (>= 1.1+ds1-6) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxau6:i386 (>= 1:1.0.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxaw7:i386 (>= 2:1.0.7-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxcb-render-util0:i386 (>= 0.3.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxcb-render0:i386 (>= 1.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxcb1:i386 (>= 1.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxcomposite1:i386 (>= 1:0.4.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxcursor1:i386 (>= 1:1.1.10-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxdamage1:i386 (>= 1:1.1.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxdmcp6:i386 (>= 1:1.0.3-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxext6:i386 (>= 2:1.1.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxfixes3:i386 (>= 1:4.0.5-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxft2:i386 (>= 2.1.14-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxi6:i386 (>= 2:1.3-6) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxinerama1:i386 (>= 2:1.1-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.7.8.dfsg-2+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxmu6:i386 (>= 2:1.0.5-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxmuu1:i386 (>= 2:1.0.5-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxp6:i386 (>= 1:1.0.0.xsf1-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxpm4:i386 (>= 1:3.5.8-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxrandr2:i386 (>= 2:1.3.0-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxrender1:i386 (>= 1:0.9.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxslt1.1:i386 (>= 1.1.26-6) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxss1:i386 (>= 1:1.2.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxt6:i386 (>= 1:1.0.7-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxtst6:i386 (>= 2:1.1.0-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxv1:i386 (>= 2:1.0.5-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxxf86vm1:i386 (>= 1:1.1.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: odbcinst1debian2:i386 (>= 2.2.14p2-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libodbc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: xaw3dg:i386 (>= 1.5+E-18) but it is not going to be installed
 skype : Depends: ia32-libs but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: ia32-libs-gtk but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@debian:~#
```

-

```
root@server:~# apt-get install ia32-libs-i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs-i386:i386 : Depends: freeglut3:i386 (>= 2.6.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: lesstif2:i386 (>= 1:0.95.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libacl1:i386 (>= 2.2.49-4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libasyncns0:i386 (>= 0.3-1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libattr1:i386 (>= 1:2.4.44-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libaudio2:i386 (>= 1.9.2-4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libaudiofile1:i386 (>= 0.2.6-8) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libavahi-client3:i386 (>= 0.6.27-2+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libavahi-common3:i386 (>= 0.6.27-2+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libbsd0:i386 (>= 0.2.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libcap2:i386 (>= 1:2.19-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libcomerr2:i386 (>= 1.41.12-4stable1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libcups2:i386 (>= 1.4.4-7+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libcurl3:i386 (>= 7.21.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libdbus-1-3:i386 (>= 1.2.24-4+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libdirectfb-1.2-9:i386 (>= 1.2.10.0-4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libdrm-intel1:i386 (>= 2.4.21-1~squeeze3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (>= 2.4.21-1~squeeze3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.21-1~squeeze3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libedit2:i386 (>= 2.11-20080614-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libesd0:i386 (>= 0.2.41-8) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libexif12:i386 (>= 0.6.19-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libexpat1:i386 (>= 2.0.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libflac8:i386 (>= 1.2.1-2+b1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libfltk1.1:i386 (>= 1.1.10-2+b1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libfontconfig1:i386 (>= 2.8.0-2.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.4.2-2.1+squeeze3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgcrypt11:i386 (>= 1.4.5-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgdbm3:i386 (>= 1.8.3-9) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 7.7.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (>= 7.7.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libglu1-mesa:i386 (>= 7.7.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgnutls26:i386 (>= 2.8.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgpg-error0:i386 (>= 1.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgphoto2-2:i386 (>= 2.4.6-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgphoto2-port0:i386 (>= 2.4.6-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 (>= 1.8.3+dfsg-4squeeze2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libice6:i386 (>= 2:1.0.6-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libidn11:i386 (>= 1.15-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libieee1284-3:i386 (>= 0.2.11-6) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libjack0:i386 (>= 1:0.118+svn3796-7) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libjpeg62:i386 (>= 6b1-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libjpeg8:i386 (>= 8b-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libk5crypto3:i386 (>= 1.8.3+dfsg-4squeeze2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libkeyutils1:i386 (>= 1.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libkrb5-3:i386 (>= 1.8.3+dfsg-4squeeze2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libkrb5support0:i386 (>= 1.8.3+dfsg-4squeeze2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: liblcms1:i386 (>= 1.18.dfsg-1.2+b3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (>= 2.4.23-7.2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libltdl7:i386 (>= 2.2.6b-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: liblzo2-2:i386 (>= 2.03-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libmpg123-0:i386 (>= 1.12.1-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libnspr4-0d:i386 (>= 4.8.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libnss-ldap:i386 (>= 264-2.2)
                       Depends: libnss3-1d:i386 (>= 3.12.8-1+squeeze4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libogg0:i386 (>= 1.2.0~dfsg-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libopenal1:i386 (>= 1:1.12.854-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libpam-ldap:i386 (>= 184-8.5)
                       Depends: libpam0g:i386 (>= 1.1.1-6.1+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libpng12-0:i386 (>= 1.2.44-1+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libpopt0:i386 (>= 1.16-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libpulse0:i386 (>= 0.9.21-3+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsamplerate0:i386 (>= 0.1.7-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsane:i386 (>= 1.0.21-9) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsasl2-2:i386 (>= 2.1.23.dfsg1-7) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsdl1.2debian:i386 (>= 1.2.15) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libselinux1:i386 (>= 2.0.96-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:i386 (>= 2.2.4.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsm6:i386 (>= 2:1.1.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsndfile1:i386 (>= 1.0.21-3+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsqlite3-0:i386 (>= 3.7.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libssh2-1:i386 (>= 1.2.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 (>= 1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libstdc++5:i386 (>= 1:3.3.6-20) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsvga1:i386 (>= 1:1.4.3-29) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libsysfs2:i386 (>= 2.1.0+repack-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libtasn1-3:i386 (>= 2.7-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libtdb1:i386 (>= 1.2.1-2+b1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libtiff4:i386 (>= 3.9.4-5+squeeze3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libts-0.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0-7) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libusb-0.1-4:i386 (>= 2:0.1.12-16) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libuuid1:i386 (>= 2.17.2-9) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libvorbis0a:i386 (>= 1.3.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libvorbisenc2:i386 (>= 1.3.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libvorbisfile3:i386 (>= 1.3.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libwrap0:i386 (>= 7.6.q-19) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libx11-6:i386 (>= 2:1.3.3-4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libx86-1:i386 (>= 1.1+ds1-6) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxau6:i386 (>= 1:1.0.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxaw7:i386 (>= 2:1.0.7-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxcb-render-util0:i386 (>= 0.3.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxcb-render0:i386 (>= 1.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxcb1:i386 (>= 1.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxcomposite1:i386 (>= 1:0.4.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxcursor1:i386 (>= 1:1.1.10-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxdamage1:i386 (>= 1:1.1.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxdmcp6:i386 (>= 1:1.0.3-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxext6:i386 (>= 2:1.1.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxfixes3:i386 (>= 1:4.0.5-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxft2:i386 (>= 2.1.14-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxi6:i386 (>= 2:1.3-6) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxinerama1:i386 (>= 2:1.1-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.7.8.dfsg-2+squeeze1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxmu6:i386 (>= 2:1.0.5-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxmuu1:i386 (>= 2:1.0.5-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxp6:i386 (>= 1:1.0.0.xsf1-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxpm4:i386 (>= 1:3.5.8-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxrandr2:i386 (>= 2:1.3.0-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxrender1:i386 (>= 1:0.9.6-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxslt1.1:i386 (>= 1.1.26-6) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxss1:i386 (>= 1:1.2.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxt6:i386 (>= 1:1.0.7-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxtst6:i386 (>= 2:1.1.0-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxv1:i386 (>= 2:1.0.5-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxxf86vm1:i386 (>= 1:1.1.0-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: odbcinst1debian2:i386 (>= 2.2.14p2-1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libodbc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: xaw3dg:i386 (>= 1.5+E-18) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@server:~#
```

sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It clearly says to try running `apt-get -f install`. Please do that.

Edit: Now that we have some better information about what's going on in your system:

It appears that you have an installed package that's newer than what's actually in the repositories. This could be because they pulled a broken package and replaced it with an older version, but your system has the newer version installed. This could also be because you installed some critical packages from unstable on your testing box.

The easiest way to recover from this situation is to do an [emergency downgrade](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_emergency_downgrading):

1. Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and make sure that you are tracking testing (currently wheezy).
2. Edit your `/etc/apt/preferences` and pin all packages to testing:

   ```
   Package: *
   Pin: release a=testing
   Pin-Priority: 1010
   ```
3. Run `apt-get dist-upgrade`. This will upgrade older packages, and downgrade newer packages, until your system is sane again.
4. Remove the above lines from `/etc/apt/preferences`.

If you really mean to be on unstable, and you were on testing before, then you probably just need to run `apt-get dist-upgrade` alone.

Comment: All this does is remove `skype`.

Comment: You mean it removed your broken previous attempt at installing `skype`. :) Now try installing the dependencies again.

Comment: Still getting all those dependencies when trying to install `ia32-libs-i386`.

Comment: You're going to have to paste again.

Comment: It's the exact same as the one already there, only it doesn't mention `apt-get -f install` or unmet dependencies at the end.

Comment: OK, well, paste it somewhere.

Comment: Pasted it in the question.

Comment: You _have_ run `apt-get update` right?

Comment: Yep. All my packages are up to date.

Comment: Added my sources.list in case it's something related to it that's wrong.

Comment: I've expanded my answer based on your clarifications. Enjoy.

Comment: `/etc/apt/preferences` doesn't seem to exist for me.

Comment: Then you create it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Downgraded to testing and the packages installed like a charm.

Answer (score 11):

You have to add i386 architecture.

This can be done with:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

and then

```
apt-get update
apt-get install packagename:i386
```

This link will give you more information: http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO

Comment: `apt-get update` is important.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue above solutions didnt work out and [this](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=23561) helped me

Answer (score 0):

In the case of ia32-libs-gtk, samir's answer is the better answer (even as it's not complete with regards to Debian squeeze) ..

In response to the numerous challenges the ia32-libs packages where posing for people on 64-bit wheezy, Debian maintainers created transitional packages for migrating those ia32 packages to multiarch .. for instance [ia32-libs-gtk-i386](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/ia32-libs-gtk-i386), etc ..

I would complete his answer by replacing his last command sample `apt-get install packagename:i386` with:

```
apt-get install ia32-libs-gtk-i386
```

Comment: Michael Hampton's answer is actually a terrible suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/513964), the following instructions helped me to solve similar problem:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get install libdbus-1-3:i386
apt-get -f install
```